# My Service does not stop when the screen is OFF

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an application, which has only one Service running in the background. I want this Service to run only when the user uses his phone, ie when the phone is unlocked, the Service records the sensor data and when the screen is locked the Service stops, But the problem is that my Service continues to record data even when the screen is off.

I have the following code and I do not see where the problem is!

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private boolean wasScreenOn = true;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    System.out.println(intent.getAction());
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)){
        wasScreenOn = true;
    }else{
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            wasScreenOn = true;


        }else{
            if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)){
                System.out.println(intent.getAction());
                wasScreenOn = false;


            }
        }
    }


    Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
    intent1.putExtra("statut", wasScreenOn);
    context.startService(intent1);


}
```

}

Code in the manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".ScreenReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name=".MyService"
        android:enabled="true" />
```

And in my service I call the receiver

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    boolean screenOn = intent.getBooleanExtra("statut", true);
    System.out.println("statut********************************************************"+screenOn);
    if(!screenOn){
   System.out.println("END********************************************************");

        try {
            unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
        }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){}

        SM.unregisterListener(this, Accelerometre);
        SM.unregisterListener(this, Gyroscope);
        SM.unregisterListener(this, Gravity);
        stopSelf();

    }


   return START_STICKY;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, declare a method in `ScreenReceiver.java`：

```
 private static boolean isServiceWorking(Context context, String serviceClassName) {
    ActivityManager myManager=(ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    ArrayList<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> runningService =
            (ArrayList<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo>) myManager.getRunningServices(30);
    for(int i = 0 ; i<runningService.size();i++) {
        if(runningService.get(i).service.getClassName().equals(serviceClassName)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

It can judge a service alive or not.Then change the code:

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
intent1.putExtra("statut", wasScreenOn);
context.startService(intent1);
```

to:

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
intent1.putExtra("statut", wasScreenOn);
if (wasScreenOn) {// if screen on
    if (!isServiceWorking(context, MyService.class.getName())) {// the service is not working
        context.startService(intent1); // start the service
    }
} else {// if screen off
    if (isServiceWorking(context, MyService.class.getName())) {// the service is working
        context.stopService(intent1); // stop the service
    }
}
```

I hope it can help you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it was really useful, however my service stops after 4 min of the screen lock I do not understand why exactly 4 min (I did several tests to check and it is always the same thing)!

Could you please explain to me this line (what is 30) : (ArrayList<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo>) myManager.getRunningServices(30);

Comment: It means fetching the latest 30(may less than 30) running services.. If your service in this list, obviously it is running.please see this ![picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlXit.png)

Comment: If that's helpful, please adopt my answer. Have a nice day! :-D